# Finding explicit formula for multiplicative inverses on m-characteristic fields?

Tags: linear-algebra

From Halmos's Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces, one of the exercises after section "Fields".

Say we define a field $Z_m$ for $m \ge 2$. This field consists of nonnegative integers $\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$. Addition is defined as regular addition $\bmod m$ (so if $m=7$ then $4+5 = 2$). Multiplication is defined similarly (so if $m=7$ then $4\cdot5 = 6$).

The book asks us to verify that $Z_m$ is a field if and only if $m$ is prime. I almost completed the whole proof but got stuck on the multiplicative inverse field axiom: each nonzero number a has a unique multiplicative inverse $(a^{-1})$ such that $a(a^{-1}) = 1$.

For example, the case of $m=7$. Each $a(a^{-1})$ must equal a multiple of $7$, plus one.

$$\frac11 = 1 \qquad
\frac12 = 4 \qquad
\frac13 = 5 \qquad
\frac14 = 2 \qquad
\frac15 = 3 \qquad
\frac16 = 6$$

I also did this with other examples of $m$. But to prove that each number has a unique multiplicative inverse, I need an explicit formula for $\frac1a$. I can't find one.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit formula (though $x^{m-1}=1$ for all $x\in Z_m$ by Fermat's little theorem).

To show this is true without an explicit formula consider $x,x^2,...,x^m$.

If any of these are zero then $x|m$ contradicting the assumption that $m$ is prime.

There are $m-1$ non zero elements in $Z_m$ so two of $x,x^2,...,x^m$ must be equal.

If $x^a=x^b$ with $a>b$ then $x^{a-b}=1$

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime then $\exists$ $a$ and $b$ such that $am+bn=1$.  Reduce this equation modulo $n$.